# I am trying to format Inlineshapes behind text in word using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to format Inlineshapes behind text in word using c#. I tried converting to shapes which is throwing error. Pls help : -

---

```
Words.Word.Application wordApp = new Words.Word.Application();  // Create word apps
Words.Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref wordPath1, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);   

start = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;               
Words.Word.Range rg1 = wordDoc.Range(ref start, ref missing);
rg1.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);

rg1.InsertAfter("\r");
rg1.InlineShapes.AddPicture(files[0], ref myTrue, ref missing, ref missing);        //Get Image to insert on word docs

rg1.InlineShapes[0].Height = 500;
rg1.InlineShapes[0].Width = 500;


rg1.InlineShapes[0].ConvertToShape(); //Throwing error
```

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: Error is : hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

Comment: this is thrown when I am trying to convert InLineshapes to shapes object using ConvertToShame() method

Comment: Is thr anyway that I can set the layout to behind text to this InLine picture ?? your help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

```
rg1.InlineShapes[0].ConvertToShape();
```

works only with .docx documents.

For maximum compatibility, use this

```
 Word.Shape MyPict = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(files[0], false, true, pointsToLeft, pointsToTop, width, height, rg1);
```

And then set the Zorder like this

```
MyPict.ZOrder(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringInFrontOfText);
```